# Highcharts polar label textoverflow

Tags: highcharts

When trying to configure a polar chart in highcharts 7.2.0 I am unable to configure the chart to always show labels on the xAxis. When the chart is not a polar chart then configuration property of xAxis.labels.styles.textOverflow = 'none' works correctly. The jsfiddle below shows that labels on the xAxis will automatically be removed if they collide with another label. I am looking to configure the polar chart to do the same thing as the line chart. When chart.polar: true is removed you can see the line chart with labels that overlap each other. 
https://jsfiddle.net/y6xor7ac/3/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
    // comment this line to show line graph working correctly
        polar: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Also known as Radar Chart'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 45,
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        overflow: 'allow',

        labels: {
            style: {
            textOverflow: 'none'
            },
          format: '{value}° super long text to make it overlap super long text to make it overlap super long text to make it overlap  '
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        overflow: 'allow',
        stackLabels: {
        allowOverlap: true
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 0,
            pointInterval: 45
        },
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Column',
        data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        pointPlacement: 'between'
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Line',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    }, {
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Area',
        data: [1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use internal `allowOverlap` property:

```
xAxis: {
    ...

    labels: {
        allowOverlap: true,
        ...
    }
},
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1rkz9sfp/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels